# Estimating overlap from subsamples (a mark-recapture problem?)

Tags: confidence-interval, capture-mark-recapture

I have a population at two time points, $N_t$ and $N_{t+1}$. Some members persist from one time point to the next, but many die out, and many are added.

**I want to know the fraction of $N_t$ that persists to $N_{t+1}$ given two subsamples of these populations.** In other words, I have a sample $P_t$ (with $P_t <<N_t$) and a sample $P_{t+1}$ (with $P_{t+1} <<N_{t+1}$), and some members are shared. I want to know, for the whole population ($N_t$ + $N_{t+1}$), the fraction of all individuals that are found in both years, and the fraction of individuals in one year persisting to the next. I don't know $N_t$ or $N_{t+1}$. I'd like to calculate confidence intervals of estimates.

My stats in this area are quite rusty, so I'd love pointers and suggestions of things to read if explicit solutions are not straightforward.

*Edit:* It looks like I need to be using a Jolly-Seber type model, which assumes open populations. I'm digging into the (vast) literature here. An additional caveat is that I have these values $P_t$ and $P_{t+1}$ for many completely independent populations--I'm uncertain how to handle that replication.

Comment: Do you know how the two samples were drawn from the population at the two time points?  More specifically, do you have good reason to believe that $P_t/N_t \approx P_{t+1}/N_{t+1}$?

Comment: I would expect $P_{t+1}/N_{t+1} < P_t/N_t$: the same absolute sampling effort was made both times, but the total population should have increased very slightly over time. But I would not expect this increase to be very large; a bigger source of error probably comes from $P << N$. In short, I could buy that approximation.